# Flutter tabController listener slow to response when swiping

Tags: flutter

I have one variable 'currentTabName' to indicate the name of tabPage. when switch tab, tablistener will be triggered to update the variable and setstate. If switch tab by clicking on the tabbar, it will be updated instantly, However I had trouble when I switching tab by swiping. It seems like there's a lag to perform the listener action.

Here is the sample code for my listener which added in initstate.

```
void _tabListener(){
   currentTabName = tabPage.name;
   setState((){});

}
```

Comment: You can refer documentation here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs OR https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, the issue is no regarding how to use tabController but there's a delay to trigger listener when swiping.

Comment: You also use animeted tab bar packages here https://fluttergems.dev/bottom-navigation-bar/

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue. It works fine when tapping on tab but is slow to respond when swiping.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a listener on the tabController.animation
This will trigger as soon as the drag gesture is started. See the example where I use it to change the Tab Bar icon. It is changed as soon as half of the necessary drag has been performed, and changed back if the dragging is reversed. It is also changed when the user taps the tab bar icon, resulting in some more if else clauses and bools.

```
class _TabTestState extends State<TabTest> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  bool _swipeIsInProgress = false;
  bool _tapIsBeingExecuted = false;
  int _selectedIndex = 1;
  int _prevIndex = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(initialIndex: _selectedIndex, length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.animation?.addListener(() {
      if (!_tapIsBeingExecuted &&
          !_swipeIsInProgress &&
          (_tabController.offset >= 0.5 || _tabController.offset <= -0.5)) {
        // detects if a swipe is being executed. limits set to 0.5 and -0.5 to make sure the swipe gesture triggered
        log("swipe  detected");
        int newIndex = _tabController.offset > 0 ? _tabController.index + 1 : _tabController.index - 1;
        _swipeIsInProgress = true;
        _prevIndex = _selectedIndex;
        setState(() {
          _selectedIndex = newIndex;
        });
      } else {
        if (!_tapIsBeingExecuted &&
            _swipeIsInProgress &&
            ((_tabController.offset < 0.5 && _tabController.offset > 0) ||
                (_tabController.offset > -0.5 && _tabController.offset < 0))) {
          // detects if a swipe is being reversed. the
          log("swipe reverse detected");
          _swipeIsInProgress = false;
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = _prevIndex;
          });
        }
      }
    });
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      _swipeIsInProgress = false;
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = _tabController.index;
      });
      if (_tapIsBeingExecuted == true) {
        _tapIsBeingExecuted = false;
      } else {
        if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
          // this is only true when the tab is changed via tap
          _tapIsBeingExecuted = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
        controller: _tabController,
        tabs: [
          Icon(_selectedIndex == 0 ? Icons.directions_car : Icons.directions_car_outlined),
          Icon(_selectedIndex == 1 ? Icons.directions_transit : Icons.directions_transit_outlined),
          Icon(_selectedIndex == 2 ? Icons.directions_bike : Icons.directions_bike_outlined),
        ],
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: const [
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
          Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used tabController animation listener from [Anica Eiting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72295093/11546366).

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);

    _tabController.animation?.addListener(() {   

      int indexChange = _tabController.offset.round();
      int index = _tabController.index + indexChange;

      if(index != _tabIndex) {
        setState(()=> _tabIndex = index);
      }

    });
  }
```

Answer (score -5):

Don't Need to listen the current tab just use it this way in tabBarView. it will remove the slow problem

```
body: TabBarView(
      children: [CricketScreen(), FootballScreen()],
    ),
```