# how to change svg image colour of tab bar by swiping? flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have svg image inside icon of tab bar . by using tab controller the colour of the icon is changing fine by pressing on the tab..but when swiping there is delay in colour change.. In many examples it is given to set the label colour. But it only works for icons and not svg image. How to do it?

here is my code...

```
           TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorWeight: 0.2,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
            indicator: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.white, blurRadius: 1)],
              color: Colors.green[300],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              TabBarBlock(
                  tabName: "Tractors",
                  tabIcon: "assets/images/othericons/tractor.svg",
                  iconColor: tabController.index == 0
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.black),
              TabBarBlock(
                  tabName: "Implements",
                  tabIcon: "assets/images/othericons/implement.svg",
                  iconColor: tabController.index == 1
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.black),
              TabBarBlock(
                  tabName: "Harvesters",
                  tabIcon: "assets/images/othericons/harvester.svg",
                  iconColor: tabController.index == 2
                      ? Colors.white
                      : Colors.black),
            ],
          ),
```

I have tried using tab controller but there is delay in colour change

```
class TabBarBlock extends StatelessWidget {
  late String tabIcon;
  late String tabName;
  late Color iconColor;
  TabBarBlock(
      {required this.tabName, required this.tabIcon, required this.iconColor});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 1,
          ),
        ],
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
      // child: Tab(
      //     text: tabName,
      //     icon: Icon(
      //       tabIcon,
      //       size: 20,
      //     )),
      child: Tab(
          text: tabName,
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
            tabIcon,
            width: 25,
            color: iconColor,
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542524/flutter-tabcontroller-listener-slow-to-response-when-swiping